# Host a sql server for remote access when isp uses NAT

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat, sql-server, postgresql

I want remote access to a postgresql(any free relational db) that I will set up at office. 
However the static IP provided to me by my ISP is not the same as the IP I get when I use [whatismyipaddress](http://whatismyipaddress.com).
I assume that my ISP is using NAT.
How should I go about it ?

Comment: which ISP do you use? Is it really your ISP assigning you IP or your IT department?

Comment: My ISP is assigning me the static IP, there is no IT dept here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the IPv4 addresses are running out. Some country who started their internet revolution late may be allocated a pool that is too small and forcing their ISP to hand out private or pseudo private (Public IPs owned by ISP) IPv4 addresses to their customer but apply carrier grade NAT.

You may want to reach out to your ISP to see what it takes to host a server. Maybe they can port forward several ports for you. Combine that with DDNS domain name, you can host a server.

But a better solution would be IPv6. That may be just what your ISP will tell you. Use IPv6 for your server and you can reach your server from the internet. As long as your server and client supports IPv6, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely this will be very easy to do. Have you considered reverse SSH tunneling to a small VPS? You can get them as cheaply as $2.50-$5.00/mo.